# Why does adding a span to an inline-block div change it's layout?

Tags: html, css

I have a bunch of dynamically generated html ([See Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xN3fq/)) that basically puts some ugly buttons on an ugly calculator in a grid, but when I try to replace an image with text in a span, the button moves down.

I'm not asking for a critique of the colors, but if someone could help me with the styling re:the alignment, that would be awesome.

Basically

```
<div><span>Text</span></div>
```

or

```
<div><div>Text</div></div>
```

appears 50% lower than:

```
<div><img src="url.jpg" /></div>
```

whereas:

```
<div>Text</div>
```

appears slightly above the image buttons in the grid if I don't mess with the font size, but:

```
<div style="font-size: 12px">Text</div>
```

moves it right back down to where the `span` had it.

The issue seems to occur independent of my javascript, as the attached fiddle has the same problem and no js in it (just the generated html and included css).

So yeah, any help other than, it's ugly?

***Note:** I chose* `display: inline-block` *intentionally for the buttons, to provide the autowrapping in the parent container. I'd prefer not to go to a* `position:fixed` *or* `position:absolute` *if that messes with the wrap around.*

Comment: Check the css on the `<div>` in, say, FireBug. There may be padding or margins that are making it move around. I think `vertical-align` works on a span in a div, too. (Not sure.)

Comment: Sorry, what is your intention?  What do you want the code at http://jsfiddle.net/xN3fq/ to do?

Comment: and don't forget that 'div' is a block-level element meaning by default it has margin on top and bottom and a line return. 'span' is an inline element and will not force a return.

Comment: I want all four buttons on the same top line with the same height

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The alignment issue you're having is the expected result of using `display: inline-block` on your `.button` elements. Using inline-block elements basically makes the element act like a block element, but its bottom aligns as an inline element would. Take this for example:

```
<p>example example example <img src="something.jpg" /></p>
```

Which renders like this:

[image: inline elements example]

The image is inline with the paragraph. Notice that the bottom of the image aligns with the bottom of the text. This same thing is happening in your Fiddle – the bottom of the `span` text aligns with the bottom of the images (once you remove the relative positioning). You have inline elements inside inline-block elements, so the bottom alignment is naturally behaving like it would on inline elements.

Inline-block elements are extremely useful, but probably not in this scenario, where you have several distinct buttons, which are in themselves distinct elements. I would suggest doing this:

```
.button {
     border: 1px outset;
     background-color: #FACC43;
     color: darkgreen;
     display: block;
     margin : 10px;
     margin-right : 0px;
     margin-bottom: 0px;
     float:left;}
```

Make the buttons block elements by using `display: block` and `float:left`. They'll behave much more predictably as elements that are 30px x 30px  on a common alignment.

If for whatever reason your really want to use inline-block, apply `vertical-alignment: bottom` to the `.button` style you currently have.

Both solutions I gave you will result in this:

[image]

Comment: Also, you mention you want autowrapping of each button. I assume by that you mean you want the buttons to continue below on the next line automatically. Again, the floating method I gave you will do that, and it's a pretty canonical and accepted method for achieving the results your looking for.

Comment: Thanks. I knew something was at work that I should understand, but I kept drawing a blank and couldn't remember why.

Answer (score 3):

You have quite a bit going on here, so I have simplified your code a bit to illustrate a few ideas to help clarify things.

Consider the following:

```
<div id="calculator">
    <div class="button">Basic</div>

    <div class="button"><span style="font-size: 30px;">Tall</span></div>

    <div class="button">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/28x28">
    </div>

    <div class="button">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/28x28" style="vertical-align: bottom;">
    </div>

    <div class="button" style="height: 28px; width: 28px;">
        <img src="no-image.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="button" style="height: 28px; width: 28px;">
        <img src="no-image.jpg" alt="alt">
    </div>

    <div class="button">
        <img src="no-image.jpg" alt="alt">
    </div>

</div>
```

and the following CSS (essentially your button style):

```
.button {
    border: 1px outset;
    background-color: #FACC43;
    color: darkgreen;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px 0px;
}
```

and the update fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/j3SRn/

[image: Demo of inline-block button layout]

Going from left to right, I show 7 buttons, on inline-blocks.

Button 1, only text, the inline-block shrinks-to-fit, simple enough.

Button 2, increase font size, again, box shrinks-to-fit, and notice that the bottom of the text shares a common baseline with Button 1.

Button 3, 28x28 image, bottom of image is on baseline, notice gap below the image.

Button 4, same as 3 but use `vertical-align: bottom` and image sits slightly lower, bottom of line box.

Button 5, in this case, the image file is not present, so a 28x28 box is drawn around the non-existent image (0x0 px dimensions) and positioned in the middle of the line, which is why it projects upward.

Button 6, no image, but this time we have alt text, wrapped in a 28x28 box, so the text falls on the baseline and the border box bits around it and projects downward.

Button 7, no image with alt text, no box size, so border shrinks to fit on text that falls on the baseline.

I hope this gives you a flavor of how inline-blocks behave, quite a flexible element.

Comment: took a look at new fiddle, appreciate the volume of information, but still not able to use it to put 4 30px divs on the same line. see updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j3SRn/2/

Comment: ? you mean like this: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/j3SRn/3/  Using inline-block or floats will do the job in this case since you know the dimensions of the buttons.

Comment: Like that, but when I change one picture to text, (no `span`), this happens: http://jsfiddle.net/j3SRn/4/

Comment: In your example, how do you want the text to be aligned?

Comment: like in @JayBeeWhy 's answer.

Comment: You can specify the line-height in the button and you can get something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/j3SRn/5/ You would need to wrap the text in a div or span if you needed finer control over the positioning.

Comment: `line-height` was the property I was thinking of. Thanks!